# Searchkick results are not relevant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a problem with a relevant search. Results of following request are very strange:

```
Candidate.search('martin', fields: [:first_name, :last_name], 
                           match: :word_start, misspellings: false).map(&:name)


["Kautzer Martina",
 "Funk Martin",
 "Jaskolski Martin",
 "Gutmann Martine",
 "Wiegand Martina",
 "Schueller Martin",
 "Dooley Martin",
 "Stiedemann Martine",
 "Bartell Martina",
 "Gerlach Martine",
 "Green Martina",
 "Lang Martine",
 "Legros Martine",
 "Ernser Martina",
 "Boehm Martina",
 "Green Martine",
 "Nolan Martin",
 "Schmidt Martin",
 "Hoppe Martin",
 "Macejkovic Martine",
 "Emard Martine"]
```

**Why Martina is going earlier than Martin?**

Searckick config:

```
searchkick language: %w(German English), word_start: [:first_name, :last_name]
```

Comment: did you ever get a solution to this? I have the same issue with searchkick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searchkick 1.4 fixes this issue. There's even a [test case](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/596eb1fb5475fb12f8e377914390e97b17ef24bd/test/autocomplete_test.rb#L64) dedicated to this question :)

Answer (score 1):

When using `word_start`, what searchkick actually does is to tokenize the chosen fields (`:first_name` and `:last_name`) using the [`searchkick_word_start_index` analyzer](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/7a197b386a21d78115dea72c9cd2e123b3c8da53/lib/searchkick/index.rb#L287). That analyzer is a custom one which uses the following edgeNGram token filter:

```
          searchkick_edge_ngram: {
            type: "edgeNGram",
            min_gram: 1,
            max_gram: 50
          },
```

So, when `Kautzer Martina` gets indexed, the following tokens are actually produced and indexed:

- `:first_name`: `m`, `ma`, `mar`, `mart`, `marti`, `martin`, `martina`
- `:last_name`: `k`, `ka`, `kau`, `kaut`, `kautz`, `kautze`, `kautzer`

Similarly, for `Funk Martin`:

- `:first_name`: `m`, `ma`, `mar`, `mart`, `marti`, `martin`
- `:last_name`: `f`, `fu`, `fun`, `funk`

As you can see, when searching for `martin`, both will match because both contain the token `martin` and they will be sorted by descending score (default). If you want to order the results differently, you can use sorting and call your `search` with

```
order: [{last_name: :asc},{first_name: :asc}]
```

Comment: Ok, but what should I use if I want to get relevant results?
In this case I need to have all records with Martin first_name in the beginning. If I sort it I will get absolutely another result:

Candidate.search('martin', fields: [:first_name, :last_name], match: :word_start, misspellings: false, order: [{last_name: :asc},{first_name: :asc}]).map(&:name)

["Bartell Martina",
 "Boehm Martina",
 "Dooley Martin",
 "Emard Martine",
 "Ernser Martina",
 "Funk Martin",
 "Gerlach Martine",
 "Green Martina",
 "Green Martine",
 "Gutmann Martine",
 "Hoppe Martin",
 "Jaskolski Martin",
 ...]

Comment: Then you should order by first_name first. Try it out.

Comment: Did you try to change the sort order to `order: [{first_name: :asc},{last_name: :asc}]` ?

Comment: This way records will be sorted by first_name firstly, but not relevant. So, for example, if I want to find by flast_name it will lead to the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    misspellings: {edit_distance: 0}

The problem with match: is you have to match the exact word, and caps.
I hope this works.